# How to list all @Test methods in the Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am using Selenium tool and Page Object Model. Currently each page has *x* number of test cases.

Eg. Login Page (Login Page elements) and LoginPageTest (corresponding validation in LoginPage used JUnit `@Test` method)

Similarly I do have multiple pages.

But to run as a whole, it seems that this is not sufficient. I need to call all the `@Test` methods in one class. If something fails, if I re-run that, then that only appears in the Junit result tab.

I don't need another one more class to contain all `@Test` methods, since each validation class has `@Test` methods. Is there any possibility to list down all the `@Test` method in JUnit? Can I run whatever the method I want to run?

Comment: Please check my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39832802/1426227). You can run multiple test methods from a project, source folder or package. To do it, right click on the project, source folder or package and then run it as a JUnit test.

Comment: Could you please let me know if [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39832802/1426227) works for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Finding test methods in Eclipse

Assuming you are using JUnit 4 and your test methods are annotated with [`@Test`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html), select the [`@Test`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html) annotation and look for its references by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.

The *Search* view should be displayed with a list of classes that contain [`@Test`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html) annotated methods. Then, in the *Search* view, click the *Expand All* button ( [image: Expand All button icon] ) to show all the test methods

### Running test methods

To run a particular test, rigth click on the test method signature (also works on the editor) and run it as a JUnit test.

If you prefer the shortcut, use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and then <kbd>T</kbd>. To debug, use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and then <kbd>T</kbd>.

### Running multiple test methods

You can run multiple test methods from a project, source folder or package. To do it, right click on the project, source folder or package and then run it as a JUnit test.

### Alternatives

AFAIK, that's all you can do to display and run JUnit tests in Eclipse. If you are open to use IntelliJ IDEA, there are some [cool features](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/run-debug-configuration-junit.html) available out-of-the-box that you can use to find JUnit test methods.

Answer (score 0):

One usability addition to Cássio response - by default the Tree with classes and methods is not expanded (only methods from one class are shown). If you want to see all the test cases this means lots of manual clicking.

Solution is to click on **Expand All**:

[image]

Comment: Yes you are correct. But i am looking something that all the methods displays so that i can run all the @Test at one shot and if something failure, i can run failures only.. I have seen this in VisualStudio which retrieve all the test methods when build the solution.. is it something possible in java/eclipse/junit as well?

Comment: I think the closest you can get is to "Re-run tests, Failures First". Failures will be started first. If all the other tests are taking long time you could simply stop this process after the failures are re-tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use grouping anotation which particular test case you to run
For Listing all Test cases , yes you cxan use in Eclipse by pressing Ctrl+Shift+G

For failure Test cases
```

Every time tests fail in a suite, TestNG creates a file called testng-failed.xml in the output directory. This XML file contains the necessary information to rerun only these methods that failed, allowing you to quickly reproduce the failures without having to run the entirety of your tests.

If you want to rerun the test exactly after the failure you need to call the method that failed. You can get that method name from ITestResult object.

If you want to rerun all the failed test cases together, then you can give the testng-failed.xml as input xml after the first execution.

Comment: The OP is using JUnit and not TestNG.